# How to close a dd process that was started in a dash script with -SIGINT?

Tags: linux, sigint, dd, dash-shell

When I start a `dd` process directly from the Terminal with

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null &
```

command, and send to it a `-SIGINT` with

```
kill -SIGINT <pid>
```

command, it closes successfully.

But when I start the process from a script

```
#!/bin/sh
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null &
```

Then do

```
kill -SIGINT <pid>
```

it doesn't affect the process.

I wonder why this is so.
I didn't find any related information on the internet.

Comment: did you use the `$!` variable to reference the pid of the most recently backgrounded process? If not, you need to do so. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[POSIX says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_11):

> If job control is disabled (see the description of set -m) when the shell executes an asynchronous list, the commands in the list shall inherit from the shell a signal action of ignored (SIG_IGN) for the SIGINT and SIGQUIT signals.

This is likely because Ctrl+C sends a sigint to every process in the group, so without this behavior, any backgrounded processes would unexpectedly be killed when you try to interrupt the main script.